# Use JSON column into a Pattern using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON files Data. Given below is a sample of it.

```
[{
"Type": "Fruit",
"Names": "Apple;Orange;Papaya"

}, {
"Type": "Veggie",
"Names": "Cucumber;Spinach;Tomato"
}]
```

I have to read the Names and match each item of the Names with a column in another df.
I am stuck at converting the value of the Names key into a list that can be used in Pattern. The code I tried is

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)


PriList=df1['Names'].str.split(";", n = 1, expand = True)

Pripat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in PriList)

df['Match'] = df['MasterList'].str.findall('('+ Pripat + ')').str.join(', ')
```

The issue is with the Pripat. Its content is

```
\bApple, Orange\b
```

If I give the Names in a list like below

```
Prilist=['Apple','Orange','Papaya']
```

the code works fine...

Please help.

Comment: `';'.join(df['Names'].values).split(';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call `str.split` and then flatten the result using `itertools.chain`.

First, do

```
df2 = df1.loc[df1.Type.eq('Fruit')]
```

Now,

```
from itertools import chain
prilist = list(chain.from_iterable(df2.Names.str.split(';').values))
```

There's also `stack` (which is slower):

```
prilist = df2.Names.str.split(';', expand=True).stack().tolist()
```

---

```
print(prilist)
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Papaya']
```

Comment: I do not want to combine the values of all the elements having the key "Name". I am searching it based on the key "Type". On using your code, the output is I get this     `['Apple, Orange']`. Basically, its a single string i.e single element in an array and that's the issue. I am not able to get it as    ` ['Apple','Orange']` i.e 2 elements in an array

Comment: It works...I had goofed up in the special character usage. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df1.loc[df1.Type.eq('Fruit')]
out_list=';'.join(df2['Names'].values).split(';')
#print(out_list)
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Papaya']
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.